# non-const find() in std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

Why for there is non-const `find()` in `std::unordered_set()`?

```
iterator find( const Key& key );
const_iterator find( const Key& key ) const;
```

`iterator` is the same as `const_iterator`, why there is non-const version of `find()`?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am talking about `find() ***const***` and `find() /* no const */` specifiers for `find()` method.

Comment: For consistency with all the other containers. Even though set keys are immutable, this allows development of templates that can work with different containers, and have those templates expect to see a container provide a suitable definition for an `iterator` member class, and a suitable `find()`.

Comment: @vladon I misunderstood the question. I thought you were asking how to use `find` to get a non-const iterator.

Comment: "iterator is the same as const_iterator" who said that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> iterator is the same as const_iterator, why there is non-const version of find()?

Because iterator is not mandatory the same as const_iterator, as stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set):

> The member types iterator and const_iterator **may be** aliases to the same type. Since iterator is **convertible** to const_iterator, const_iterator should be used in function parameter lists to avoid violations of the One Definition Rule.

emphasis is mine. Since they are not mandatory the same some generic code can depend on particular type of iterator returned by `find()` and it should be consistent with other containers.